# Could not find the following Boost libraries: boost_asio

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, boost-asio

When I try to compile my cmake project, which uses boost and asio, with `make` I get these errors:

```
CMakeFiles/client-network-handler-test.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `__cxx_global_var_init1':
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:222: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'    CMakeFiles/client-network-handler-test.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `__cxx_global_var_init1':
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:222: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
CMakeFiles/client-network-handler-test.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `__cxx_global_var_init2':
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:223: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
CMakeFiles/client-network-handler-test.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `__cxx_global_var_init3':
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:224: undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
CMakeFiles/client-network-handler-test.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `boost::asio::error::get_system_category()':
/usr/include/boost/asio/error.hpp:216: undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
../../lib/libclient-network-handler.a(ClientNetworkHandler.cpp.o): In function `__cxx_global_var_init1':
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:222: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
../../lib/libclient-network-handler.a(ClientNetworkHandler.cpp.o): In function `__cxx_global_var_init2':
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:223: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
../../lib/libclient-network-handler.a(ClientNetworkHandler.cpp.o): In function `__cxx_global_var_init3':
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:224: undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
../../lib/libclient-network-handler.a(ClientNetworkHandler.cpp.o): In function `boost::network::uri::uri::parse()':
/home/darren/373project/include/boost/network/uri/uri.hpp:178: undefined reference to `boost::network::uri::detail::parse(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string>, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string>, boost::network::uri::detail::uri_parts<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string> >&)'
../../lib/libclient-network-handler.a(ClientNetworkHandler.cpp.o): In function `error_code':
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:323: undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
CMakeFiles/client-network-handler-test.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `__cxx_global_var_init2':
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:223: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
CMakeFiles/client-network-handler-test.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `__cxx_global_var_init3':
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:224: undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
CMakeFiles/client-network-handler-test.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `boost::asio::error::get_system_category()':
/usr/include/boost/asio/error.hpp:216: undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
../../lib/libclient-network-handler.a(ClientNetworkHandler.cpp.o): In function `__cxx_global_var_init1':
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:222: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
../../lib/libclient-network-handler.a(ClientNetworkHandler.cpp.o): In function `__cxx_global_var_init2':
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:223: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
../../lib/libclient-network-handler.a(ClientNetworkHandler.cpp.o): In function `__cxx_global_var_init3':
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:224: undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
../../lib/libclient-network-handler.a(ClientNetworkHandler.cpp.o): In function `boost::network::uri::uri::parse()':
/home/myUserName/373project/include/boost/network/uri/uri.hpp:178: undefined reference to `boost::network::uri::detail::parse(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string>, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string>, boost::network::uri::detail::uri_parts<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string> >&)'
../../lib/libclient-network-handler.a(ClientNetworkHandler.cpp.o): In function `error_code':
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:323: undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
```

I gather that the asio library cannot be found. So I add this line to my root CMakeLists.txt:

```
find_package(Boost 1.54.0 REQUIRED)
```

And CMake can find all the relevant libraries, as shown by this part of the build log:

```
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   unit_test_framework
--   system
--   regex
--   date_time
--   thread
--   filesystem
--   program_options
--   chrono
--   atomic
```

But compilation still produces the first error listed. When I change that CMake line to:

```
find_package(Boost 1.54.0 REQUIRED asio)
```

I get this message from CMake:

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1131 (message):
  Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

  Boost version: 1.54.0

  Boost include path: /usr/include

  Could not find the following Boost libraries:

          boost_asio
```

I have all the Boost libraries installed, as you can see, and I can't understand why it can't find asio.

Comment: Are you compiling a library or an executable? It's pretty important, because how you must configure boost for correctly using asio changes whether you're building asio into a lib or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Boost.Asio is a header-only library - i.e. it doesn't need linked to your application.

From [the docs for CMake's `FindBoost` module](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/module/FindBoost.html):

> This module finds headers and requested **component** libraries

(emphasis mine).

In other words, `find_package(Boost ...)` should only be used to find Boost libraries which are non-header-only, as listed in the [Boost docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html#header-only-libraries).

From your linker errors, it looks like you *do* need to link Boost.System though:

```
find_package(Boost 1.54.0 REQUIRED system)
target_include_directories(MyExe PRIVATE ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(MyExe ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

Comment: I added these lines: `target_include_directories(client-network-handler-test ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS} PUBLIC)
target_link_libraries(client-network-handler-test client-network-handler ${Boost_SYSTEM_LIBRARY} ${Boost_FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY} ${Boost_SYSTEM_LIBRARY}   ${Boost_REGEX_LIBRARY})` in the directory for the executable. The problem persists

Comment: In your `target_include_directories` call, the `PUBLIC` must come before `${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}` - but that's not the issue here.  Are you just doing `find_package(Boost 1.54.0 REQUIRED)` now, or are you specifying the individual Boost components?  Are you calling `find_package(Boost ...)` *before* calling `target_link_libraries` (try printing the value of `${Boost_SYSTEM_LIBRARY}` just before the `target_link_libraries` call to confirm).

Comment: Unless otherwise configured, ::asio explicitly relies on boost::system, because it uses error codes/structs defined in boost::system. So that's at least one issue, is that you need to link to ::system.