# cmake - ros - how to include boost (C++)

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, ros

I have a ROS-JADE-Project which compiles fine. However when I start my launch file I got 2 main errors:

```
rtkrcv_node: /usr/include/boost/optional/optional.hpp:631: 
boost::optional<T>::reference_type boost::optional<T>::get() [with T = 
SolutionData; boost::optional<T>::reference_type = SolutionData&]: Assertion 
`this->is_initialized()' failed. 


***** Internal Program Error - assertion (i < N) failed in T& boost::array<T, 
N>::operator[](boost::array<T, N>::size_type) [with T = double; long unsigned
 int N = 2000ul; boost::array<T, N>::reference = double&; boost::array<T, 
N>::size_type = long unsigned int]: 
/usr/include/boost/array.hpp(123): out of range
```

In my programm in the .hpp files I use the following boost libraries:

boost::array
boost::optional

I think these two errors above are caused, because I did not build my code correctly with my CMakeLists.txt file. Currently I mainly do the following to build my two nodes:

```
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
link_directories(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIR})
add_executable(rviz_node
src/rviz_sub.cpp)
add_dependencies(rviz_node ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
target_link_libraries(rviz_node
 ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
m
rt
pthread
)

add_definitions(-DENAGLO -DENAGAL -DENACMP -DENAQZS -DNFREQ=6 -DTRACE -DNEXOBS=3)
add_executable(rtkrcv_node
  src/main.cpp
  src/ros_options.cpp
  src/rtkrcv.cpp
)
add_dependencies(rtkrcv_node ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
target_link_libraries(rtkrcv_node
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
  m
  rt
  pthread
)
```

I also tried to include the boost library but nothing I tried worked yet. 
My Boost version is 1.54.0 
I got the same problem as announced here ([Could not find the following Boost libraries: boost_asio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33091417/could-not-find-the-following-boost-libraries-boost-asio)), cause I also want to use Array and Optional Boost lib....
however If I try e.g:

```
    find_package(Boost 1.54.0 REQUIRED system)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
link_directories(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIR})
add_executable(rviz_node
src/rviz_sub.cpp)
add_dependencies(rviz_node ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
target_include_directories(rviz_node PRIVATE ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(rviz_node
 ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
 ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
m
rt
pthread
)
```

Further details according to the first error:
My rtkrcv.cpp file looks like:

```
...
boost::optional<SolutionData> getSolution () {
  boost::optional<SolutionData> data; 
....
}
```

My rtkrcv.hpp file looks like:

```
#include <boost/optional.hpp>
...
boost::optional<SolutionData> getSolution ();
struct SolutionData {
...
};
```

In my main.cpp I do the following:

```
...
 auto sol = getSolution(); // opens rtkrcv.cpp
...
...
```

Comment: This error has nothing to do with how you are building your project, but with your code instead.

Comment: I guess it has cause i just changed my code and did not use boost::array and a normal array instead and the second error above did not show up anymore ....

Comment: You do see that it says "assertion failed" and "out of range"? That is likely because you are doing out of range array access on you boost::array. Of course, the error vanishes when using normal arrays since they don't implement bounds checking. If you want help, you will need to show us your actual code.

Comment: Yeah I just try to give minimal example of my code cause it is quite huge .... :( anyway i do not get it where there is still an error according to how I use boost:optional wrong .....

Comment: I can only guess, but the error seems to stem from the fact that you use `get()` on a `boost::optional` which doesn't actually contain a value. You should make sure to check all your optionals before you access the encapsulated object.

Comment: Provide code as [mcve]. You have runtime-error, and your current code lines are obviously insufficient to reproduce it.